# PHP: Treat arrays like objects (like in js)

Tags: php, arrays

In JS you could have something like this:

```
var a = [1, 2, 3];
a.myProp = false;
```

This is possible because in js array are actually objects.

What I'm trying to do is to implement the same, but in PHP.

The closest solution I've found is to use the [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) class, but the main problem of this "solution" is that it is object and when you check with `is_array` or try to use other specific array method it will return false or throw error.

Is there any magic php method like `__construct` or sth similar for arrays?

In general - I want to add some kind of a flag separated from the array values. For example:

```
$a = [1, 2, 3];

$a.alreadyIterated = false;

foreach ($a as $item) {
...
}

$a.alreadyIterated = true;
...

if (!$a.alreadyIterated) {
    foreach($a as $item) {...}
}
```

Comment: Simple answer is: you cannot. You can still implement ArrayAccess interface to object (http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) or use ArrayObject etc., but in fact you never get answer `true` to `is_array`...

Comment: It's unclear what your end goal is here. As a general rule, trying to use one language the same way as another language just is not the right thing to do, since each language has its own idioms. Note that PHP arrays are actually hash tables, so you can have something like `$a = [1, 2, 3]; $a['key'] = false;`.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: Why you not create your own object with `memory` if it was complete iterated or not? - it's ideally thing for Traversable interface (http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php)...

Comment: @tomas.lang the iterator prop was just one example usage.

Comment: And if you want real array and have `alreadyIterated` in "scope" with it, you can still composite it to something like `class XXX {public $array; public $alreadyIterated;}`

Comment: @tomas.lang Yeah, but then I will have to work with the specific class, not the array itself. Maybe that I want is too ridiculously.

Comment: Problem is that PHP have strong limitations in this... And therefore i must only come out from concrete examples... I didn't see any general solution, except that mentioned composition...

Comment: What's the problem with working with the specific class?  It seems to be this is exactly what you want, a combination of an array and an object, so using an array inside an object seems to be the solution.

Comment: @Devon nevermind, I will stuck with ArrayObject. Sorry for taking your time guys.

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat possible via creating your own class:

```php
class PropArray implements ArrayAccess, Iterator {
   public $alreadyIterated = false;
   protected $a = []; # internal array for iterable values

   # add required methods from the interfaces, pretty easy
}
```

Instances will still be objects, but can be iterated like arrays and tested via `is_array($obj) || $obj instanceof Traversable`.